# Python, elegant way to test for a set/list/tuple, expecting strings

Tags: python, arrays, string, set, typechecking

I'm building an SQL query's Regex, which I'm passing to a Python function. Here's what I'm currently doing (`iterable` is a variable passed to the function):

```
if isinstance(iterable, (list, tuple, set)):
    app = '|'.join(iterable)
```

I'd like to be able to test for an abstraction (see the collection module's ABC's) that means that it's a container, but not a `basestring`. (which is iterable!)

Is there a way to improve on the above?

Comment: `isinstance(iterable, collections.Container) and not isinstance(iterable, str)` ?

Comment: Sorry, was responding to an earlier comment which claimed that `iterable` was a native type. there is an `Iterable` in collections, but no `iterable` afaik. The comment was deleted, so i guess they got mixed up with a different language?

Comment: I'd just do: `if not isinstance(iterable, basestring): app = '|'.join(iterable)`. Don't check for specific sequences... leave it to duck-typing and just document that you want an iterable of strings or a string.

Comment: @Bakuriu That did occur to me, but you should write it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think any such thing exists - what you have may be the best.

Occasionally, I have functions that take either strings (which i'll split) or an iterable of strings. For those, I usually go for a negative test instead i.e.

```
if isinstance(iterable, basestring):
    iterable = iterable.split(',')
```

etc.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I'll +1 for the effort, but I'm hoping I get told there's a better way.

Comment: Well, the problem is that you don't want to test for type, you want to test for functionality, either implicitly (duck-type) or explicitly(using ABC, instancing from base classes, or functions like `callable`). So, first you need to define what abstract functionality you want that should pass for iterables, and fail for strings. Normally, there isn't an easy one.

Comment: Accepting, since there isn't a better way!